# How to read content of _setup.xml file from .CAB file

Tags: windows-ce, cab

Platform are wince5.0 and 6.0.
As you know that we can add some information in to *.inf file such as write some data into registry when installing .cab before generating .CAB. 
Now, my program is running on wince5.0 and 6.0. I want to retrieve version information from _setup.xml (because I set it in *.inf before generating .cab file). 
But it seems that there is no library or class which could be used to unpack .cab file or read the content from .cab file.  (I know that there is a DLL/lib in windows platform or advanced version of .NET).

Is there any good idea to reach my target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I'm aware of is the [CAB Installer SDK](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2008/08/01/AnnouncingTheCABInstallerSDK.aspx), which supports uncompressed and compressed CABs.

**EDIT**

The CAB Installer SDK source [is now available free over on CodePlex](http://cab.codeplex.com/).

Comment: yeah, that's for .NET usage, but what I need is for native code and can running on windows CE. Till now, I still can't find it.

Comment: Well the Installer SDK does run on CE and the code's pretty small so it could feasibly be ported to C++.

Comment: I checked the CAB Installer SDK, it seems that this SDK is not free. We need to buy it (and not sure if it includes the source code) which is out of my scope. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: Well the price starts at $5 - that's really a barrier?